# What is meant by implementation of Java?

Tags: java

I was going through a thread in which there was discussion around whether Java is open source or not. There were few answers which were referring to implementation of Java.

Is there a specification for Java? Can anyone write there own implementation as long as it adheres to the specification? Where is this specification documented?

Thanks.

Comment: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/   See this

Comment: Thanks James. Does this specification keep getting updated with each Java release? Who owns this specification and who certifies if a java implementation complies to this specification? Using which programming language is a Java implementation written - for example which language was used by Sun to write the implementation. I will post a new question if all these should be part of a new question.

Comment: Anyone can follow the JLS. It takes a battery of test (and $$$?) to claim to be Java (compatible), however. Microsoft failed to do this back in the 90's -- then they decided not to support Java at all :-)

Comment: @PunterVicky, all your questions are answered in the shared link and inside the document.

Comment: Thanks James - will go through it!

Comment: @PunterVicky, although I've never looked into the language used for Sun's JVM, writing virtual machines is something which would often be done in C/C++, perhaps some assembly as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Java" can refer to the Java platform, which executes Java bytecode, and the Java language. There are specifications for both. Besides the official implementations from Sun, other organizations have created alternate implementations of both. For a specification of the Java language, see the book "The Java Programming Language" by James Gosling.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Are there any specification largely at use apart from the one provided by Sun(or Oracle now)? Why would anyone what to create a whole implementation - isn't a major piece of work?

Comment: Sure, it's a huge piece of work. That's why I said other "organizations" have made their own implementations, not "individuals". For example: IBM had their own Java Virtual Machine, called "Jikes" -- I don't know if it is still around or if they have abandoned it. I believe that Eclipse uses its own Java compiler rather than the Sun Java compiler. (Others, please correct me if necessary.) As to *why*... well, I'm sure they had different reasons in each case. You'll have to research individual cases.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.
Sun published the [specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls).

Answer (score 1):

[Java language specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/)

[apache Harmony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Harmony) is one implementation example,of course APache community voted to discontinue